# download progress with jsonp via ajax

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

In an internet very many example how extend $.ajax for get download (or upload) progress. 
[This example](https://github.com/englercj/jquery-ajax-progress/blob/master/js/jquery.ajax-progress.js) work perfect with plain-text, xml, json, but not work with jsonp. There are no reaction from event-listeners. I wrote this example on pure javascript, but no result. I know about script-append-to-DOM-way. Using this method can not get progress.
How i can get download **progress** with jsonp and via XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know about script-append-to-DOM-way.

JSONP **is** the script-append-to-DOM-way. There are no "progress" events on script tags AFAIK.